# JavaScript variable scope from filereader() function

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with the scope in the filereader() code i have. I have two console.logs() outputting the data from a JSON file uploaded. One outputs as expected, within the function parsing the JSON. The other outputs the 'template' data/object. It looks to me like its a scope issue. Where should i define the updated character object to have the parsed JSON data update the character object?

The function should import a JSON file, parse it then string it into a textarea and also take the parse and put the output into a character object referable by the whole page.

The character object being imported, is an exported version of the character object from another user session.

```
$('#import').click(function(){

  var iData = document.getElementById('selectFiles').files;
  console.log(iData);
  if (iData.length <= 0) {
    return false;
  }

  var file = new FileReader();

  file.onload = function(x) { 
    console.log(x);
    var output = JSON.parse(x.target.result);
    var stringed = JSON.stringify(output,null,2);
    document.getElementById('result').value = stringed;
    character = output;
    console.log(character); //this outputs the data as expected
  }

  console.log(character);//this outputs blank 'template' data
  file.readAsText(iData.item(0));
});
```

I posted something similar to this the other day, but the post was a bit.... bad, if i'm honest. Hopefully i've poked about enough to make this one a little better.

Thanks

Comment: `console.log(character);//this outputs blank 'template' data` is fired already before the `onload` function is finished. By that time, `character` variable is still not updated by your callback.

Comment: Thank you, i can work with this. Ill also check out the dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console.log that works is inside of your `onload` function, this means it won't get called until the function successfully loads your JSON. The second console.log doesn't work because it is called before your JSON has a chance to load.